# How to get cropper size in react-cropper?

Tags: reactjs, cropperjs

I am using react-cropper in my project. How to get crop box width and height like in the crop options of example below.
[image]

Comment: check this code-sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-pine-i7fs3

Comment: I have checked your link, but I mean I need to get the value of the cropper height and width. I didn't found it in your link.

Answer (score 1):

if you are setting it up like this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-pine-i7fs3?file=/src/Demo.tsx:397-404)

then you can get width and height using useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (cropper) {
      const { top, left, width, height } = cropper?.imageData;
      // console.log('width, width)
    }
  }, [cropper]);
```

Comment: Nice. But how to get the value every time I resize the cropbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cropmove (this event fires when the canvas (image wrapper) or the crop box is changing).

```
const cropperRef = useRef(null);

const onCropMove = (e) => {
    const cropper = cropperRef.current.cropper;
    const {width, height} = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
    
    console.log(width, height);
};


<Cropper
  ref={cropperRef}
  src={image}
  cropmove={onCropMove}
/>
```